# RepeatButton's ClickMode broken in winrt?

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

The ClickMode for RepeatButtons in Windows 8 Store apps isn't working as I expect. Am I doing it wrong or has anyone noticed these issues:

- ClickMode=Release and ClickMode=Press behave the same. When using the mouse or touch, holding the button continues to fire the click event. I thought that Release would make a RepeatButton work more or less like a regular Button--one click per mousedown/mouseup.
- Using the keyboard, the click event isn't raised at all using Enter. (Using Spacebar works.)
- Setting the clickmode in a style isn't picked up by the control.

I was using RepeatButtons, but test wanted to change the click events to only fire once. I thought ClickMode would be a fast fix but had to replace them with Buttons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's what a RepeatButton does. If you want to get a single click per press - use a regular Button control.

Comment: Hm. I thought it worked differently in WPF but I guess it doesn't.

Comment: Right, I think that ClickMode mostly applies to a regular button where depending on your application design you might override the base behavior and switch from the Click event being raised when someone releases the button to either when it gets first pressed or when used with a mouse - when someone hovers the cursor on top of it.